# Matlab gui text update doesn't work

Tags: matlab

Okay, so I have built a GUI in Matlab that, while executing the main function has text displaying "Processing...". After this is finished it says "Done!", however the user has a checkbox option to create a movie. I'm therefore trying to get it to say "Creating Movie File..." while it's doing this part but it won't change from saying "Processing..."

Here's the code:

```
set(handles.text5,'String','Processing...')
mov = main(days,viewpoint,planets,makemov,names);
if strcmp(makemovie,'y') == 1
    set(handles.text5, 'String', 'Creating Movie File...')
    moviemaker(mov, movname)
    set(handles.text5, 'String', 'Done!')
else
    set(handles.text5, 'String', 'Done!')
end
```

I know the if statement is executing properly because it does create the movie if I check the box however I can't work out why it won't display "Creating Movie File..."

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You may want to refresh the GUI. Try following instructions from http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/refresh-gui-data-display-at-set-intervals-guide.html

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working, turns out I just needed to throw in a few "drawnow()" lines.